# Running gradle commands inside a task

Tags: gradle

Is there any way by which i can run `gradle clean`, `gradle compile`and `gradle publish` commands inside a gradle task in `build.gradle` on a windows pc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `taskX.dependsOn taskY` where `taskX` is the task you will be running (in this case, `build`) and where `taskY` is the task that must be run before the current task. You could also use `taskY.shouldRunAfter taskX` for a task that should run after the current task. Note that these statement shouldn't be called from within the task.

`build.dependsOn publish` will run the `publish` task before running the `build` task.

I suggest you read through [Ordering Tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:ordering_tasks) in the gradle doc.

---

If you really need to call a task from another task, you can, but there are better options - such as those above. Using `tasks.taskX.execute()` will do what you're looking for. Where taskX is the task you want to execute. This can be called from within a task.

---

To address your comment.

This code will run the tasks: `clean`, `compile` and `publish` before `build` is executed:

```
build.dependsOn clean
build.dependsOn compile
build.dependsOn publish
```

This code will run the tasks: `clean`, `compile` and `publish` after `build` has been executed:

```
build.shouldRunAfter clean
build.shouldRunAfter compile
build.shouldRunAfter publish
```

This code will run the task: `clean` before `build` is executed and run: `compile` and `publish` after build has been executed:

```
build.dependsOn clean
build.shouldRunAfter compile
build.shouldRunAfter publish
```

This is probably the code you're looking for. Add the configuration which best suits your needs before the `build` task has been declared. Then when executing `build.gradle`, execute the task `build` from the command line.

Comment: This is helpful, but what commands/code do i need to write to execute those 3 gradle commands.

Comment: right now i am doing this `task sourceJar (type: Exec) {
                //baseName = "${project.name}-11"
                //from sourceSets.test.output
    
workingDir "commons"
commandLine 'gradle clean'}`

Comment: in these i have to make tasks of clean, compile or publish and in them i have to write code aging to perform those functions on command line, i want to know the code which will be inside the task and will run in command line when calling the task